# Getting a HASP key with C/C++ (Problem)

Tags: c++, c, debugging

I seem to be in need of some help (and by some, I mean a lot).

Im trying to make a C program (or c++ if I get it to work, the language is not really important) to connect to a HASP USB. HASP is basically a USB drive that has some unique codes. The purpose of the HASP is to basically just "secure" another program, so that it only runs while the HASP is connected to the computer.

First of all, let me say that I am actually trying to get it to work, not hacking another one. I am using the demo key for development, for now, although I have a master key.

This HASP program features a toolbox, that should generate the code in C ready to copy paste and get it to work. But, it doesent actually work, or at least, its not just copy paste.

(For more information about HASP, go http://www2.safenet-inc.com/google/SRM/dk-hasp.asp?CID=GooIntl-IND&HBX_PK=hasp&HBX_OU=50&CMP=KNC-GoogleAdd&wcw=google&_kk=hasp&_kt=e9b07d11-6db3-4153-a46b-5dc95204b6a3&gclid=CJfxibrp-qUCFRQv3wodBnwfpA )

Unfortunately, I do NOT have any kind of C or C++ coding experience, so I am having several problems trying to work this out. I only programmed the other part in Director (similar to Flash).

The code it gives me just for making a login (read, connection) to the HASP is the following:

```
const hasp_feature_t feature = HASP_DEFAULT_FID;

hasp_handle_t handle = HASP_INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
hasp_status_t status;


//This is a code needed to login, its just the demo code for now, but it matches
//the HASP i'm using

unsigned char vendor_code[] =

"AzIceaqfA1hX5wS+M8cGnYh5ceevUnOZIzJBbXFD6dgf3tBkb9cvUF/Tkd/iKu2fsg9wAysYKw7RMAsV"
"vIp4KcXle/v1RaXrLVnNBJ2H2DmrbUMOZbQUFXe698qmJsqNpLXRA367xpZ54i8kC5DTXwDhfxWTOZrB"
"rh5sRKHcoVLumztIQjgWh37AzmSd1bLOfUGI0xjAL9zJWO3fRaeB0NS2KlmoKaVT5Y04zZEc06waU2r6"
"AU2Dc4uipJqJmObqKM+tfNKAS0rZr5IudRiC7pUwnmtaHRe5fgSI8M7yvypvm+13Wm4Gwd4VnYiZvSxf"
"8ImN3ZOG9wEzfyMIlH2+rKPUVHI+igsqla0Wd9m7ZUR9vFotj1uYV0OzG7hX0+huN2E/IdgLDjbiapj1"
"e2fKHrMmGFaIvI6xzzJIQJF9GiRZ7+0jNFLKSyzX/K3JAyFrIPObfwM+y+zAgE1sWcZ1YnuBhICyRHBh"
"aJDKIZL8MywrEfB2yF+R3k9wFG1oN48gSLyfrfEKuB/qgNp+BeTruWUk0AwRE9XVMUuRbjpxa4YA67SK"
"unFEgFGgUfHBeHJTivvUl0u4Dki1UKAT973P+nXy2O0u239If/kRpNUVhMg8kpk7s8i6Arp7l/705/bL"
"Cx4kN5hHHSXIqkiG9tHdeNV8VYo5+72hgaCx3/uVoVLmtvxbOIvo120uTJbuLVTvT8KtsOlb3DxwUrwL"
"zaEMoAQAFk6Q9bNipHxfkRQER4kR7IYTMzSoW5mxh3H9O8Ge5BqVeYMEW36q9wnOYfxOLNw6yQMf8f9s"
"JN4KhZty02xm707S7VEfJJ1KNq7b5pP/3RjE0IKtB2gE6vAPRvRLzEohu0m7q1aUp8wAvSiqjZy7FLaT"
"tLEApXYvLvz6PEJdj4TegCZugj7c8bIOEqLXmloZ6EgVnjQ7/ttys7VFITB3mazzFiyQuKf4J6+b/a/Y";

status = hasp_login(feature, vendor_code, &handle);

/* check if operation was successful */
if (status != HASP_STATUS_OK)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case HASP_FEATURE_NOT_FOUND:
            break;
        case HASP_HASP_NOT_FOUND:
            break;
        case HASP_OLD_DRIVER:
            break;
        case HASP_NO_DRIVER:
            break;
        case HASP_INV_VCODE:
            break;
        case HASP_FEATURE_TYPE_NOT_IMPL:
            break;
        case HASP_TMOF:
            break;
        case HASP_TS_DETECTED:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And the error:

```
hasp_demo.cpp|44|error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token|
hasp_demo.cpp|47|error: expected unqualified-id before 'if'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I know this is a very specific help request, but I'm completely lost now and don't know what to do from now on. I tried playing around with the code, but it always gets me errors.

Also, im on windows, using GNU GCC Compiler in Codeblocks IDE.

Comment: This is not very specific, the problems you are having are normal C++ problems and not related to HASP.

Comment: Don't use `<code>` tags to format your code. If you'd looked at the preview while writing your question, you'd see that it *doesn't work*. Instead, use the `101010` button to format code.

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion Jalf. Sorry for not knowing these things, I'm still just a newbie here, so everything is all new for now.

Comment: FYI: i worked with HASP once aswell.. but they really had outdated linux drivers only ... so we switched to Unikey dongles, which worked nicely aswell, but IIRC only cost 50% of HASP dongles... and you can get free evualation kits somewhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you pasted seems like an example how to use the API, not a working program by itself. It does not seem like it is intended to compile.

So I guess you need to learn C/C++, or find someone at your job who can help.

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid of that, but since I have no actual ideia how the code is supposed to work, I was hoping there was something stupid I was missing. Thanks for your reply though, at least now I now where to go for from here.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my question: [C# HASP login code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147006/c-sharp-hasp-login-code)
This is same situation as in here. This code should work as stated in HASP SDK. You can use it as it is in any function and you should log in to the hasp key. I think that it won't work with demo master key(DEMOMA) because they simply block it.Though it's strange because you can test this with code withing the sample code generator application called Sentinel HASP Toolbox and then it works as expected and described in docs.