# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object - HASP HL dongle

Tags: .net, usb, delphi-prism, dongle, hasp

I am trying to add reference to my Delphi Prism project for HASP HL. So, I can communicate with the USB HASP HL dongle.

After the initial set up, I couldn't get my program to communicate with the USB HASP HL dongle. So, I watched a youtube tutorial video by SafeNet or Alladdin and followed their instruction to the teeth exactly, but I ran into another problem, which I can't seem to figure out.

As part of the HASP HL dongle setup, I am supposed to add reference for **hasp_net_demo.dll** to my project. Everytime I try to do that, I keep getting this error, **Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object**, and it won't let me add the reference. I learned that along with **hasp_net_window.dll** reference you also need to add reference to **hasp_net_demo.dll**, because it has the actual namespace and class to communicate with your HASP HL dongle.

So, what can I do at this point? or What options do I have?

Please, help. I have been looking at this problem for the last 3 months on and off and still can't find a solution.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you try mailing prism support? Sounds like an IDE bug but I've never seen those dlls myself.

Comment: I have number of times and they have yet to respond to my emails. I found their tutorial videos on Youtube. I try to follow them hoping that I will be able to make some progress, but as you can see, I basically came to a dead-end it seems. If you are using their HASP dongle, then these dlls should be in your program files/Safenet or Alladdin folder.

Comment: I meant support for Delphi Prism (remobjects or embarcadero)

Comment: Ck, Well, in way it was Safenet problem. The dll files I was using are not the right ones apparently. In fact, they told me to download the latest dll files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue. First, you need to make sure that you are writing application for framework 4.0. If you are, then you need to download their latest Runtime API for .NET dll files.

Sentinel HASP DotNET Runtime API

```
apidsp_windows.dll
apidsp_windowsx64.dll
hasp_net_windows.dll
hasp_windows_xxxxx.dll
```

Put them all in your project folder. Then, add reference to hasp_net_windows.dll file to your project file.

Then, you are done.

Comment: If anyone interested, this question is also related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760673/hasp-hl-working-demo-needed-for-c-sharp